# SpringBoot project as dependency in another SpringBoot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have 2 Spring Boot projects.
Project 1 - IOP has a package GeneratedClasses that I want to use in the other Spring project. To achieve this I have put the following in the POM.xml of IOP:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

On Project 2 - ExternalAPI I have added the reference to the IOP project like this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>IOP</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I have done mvn clean install on IOP and I can see the folder in .m2 repo with the jar file included.
However, when I try to do mvn clean install on ExternalAPI (project 2 with the dependency) I get the error:
package com.example.IOP.GeneratedClasses.InternalEndpoints.ExternalAPIControlers does not exist

I have checked other posts but I am still facing this issue and so wanted to ask how do I solve this?